# knex.raw with existing columns array using .first statement

Tags: node.js, knex.js

Here is existing code:

```
       knex("products")
           .first("id", "name", "ingredients")
       ...
```

So, currently it just uses array of column names.

Now I want to add calculated column here. It would consists of "constant" + product.id. 
For product with id 1 it would be `"api/v1/img/1"`.
For product with id 222 it would be `"api/v1/img/222"`.
**Alias** of it should be `"image"`.

I have to use knex.raw somehow. Do not understand how and what is the correct syntax to use it with `.first()`.

Answer (score 1):

I'm sorry, I'm unable to understand the question. What kind of result are you trying to achieve? maybe something like this?

```
knex("products")
  .select('*', knex.raw(`'api/v1/img' || ?? as computed`, ['products.id']))
  .first()
```

Like this: https://runkit.com/embed/9okme0czge8z

Comment: I have rephrased my question.